# INSERT into same table from SELECT CASE; Query gives no errors; No updates

Tags: mysql

Currently working on a problem set for learning purposes.

The goal was to update the column `amount2` based on the values of `amount.

```
INSERT INTO price_db(id, amount, amount2)
SELECT asin, amount,
     (
    CASE 
        WHEN amount = '0.00' THEN 999.99
        WHEN amount <= '7.99' THEN 9.99
        ELSE amount
    END) AS amount2
from price_db
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id= values(id)
```

When I run this, I don't have any issues with the query - but the column `amount2` doesn't actually update with any new values?

What am I doing wrong here...? Unless this query is not "allowed"?

Much thanks

Comment: Please provide DDL for your price_db table - SHOW CREATE TABLE price_db;

Comment: If you want to edit your question, comment on answers, or accept one, you will need to use the same device and browser you used to ask the question *without clearing cookies* since you used an unregistered account. I see you now have a registered (login-based) account, so you could also [request a merge of your accounts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) after which your registered account will own the question.

Answer (score 3):

if Goal - **update the column amount2 based on the values of amount**

all more simple:

```
UPDATE price_db
SET amount2 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN amount = 0.00 THEN 999.99
        WHEN amount <= 7.99 THEN 9.99
        ELSE amount
    END
```

and remove ' ' around decimal values it work, but wrong construction

Comment: Thanks Vlad!
This works... What if I want to update more than 1 column in the query? For example a `stock` column based on the condition of `amount`? Thanks,

Comment: all the same, just need to accurate - bulk update could damage data. so test before run over real data-set